# how to set and get parent variables from child classes - mvc

Tags: php, class

I have a mvc script.

```
$load = new $controller($modelName, $action);
if (method_exists($load, $action)){
    $load->{$action}($query);
}
```

and I am creating extended classes:

```
class testController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct($model, $action)
    {
        parent::__construct($model, $action);
        $this->_setModel($model);
    }
}
```

Here is my question, I would like to set a variable in controller and can get and change it by extended classes.
for example:

```
class Controller
{
var $myvar="defaultCaption";
}
```

and change it by extended classes, for example, change it by one extended class, then get new value from another extended class. but it is just load default value.

I want something works like this:

```
class Controller
{
    protected $myvar="defaultCaption";

    public function __construct() 
    {
     }
}

class myController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class myController2 extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

$mc = new myController; 
$mc->myvar= "XXX";

$mc2= new myController2;
echo ($mc2->myvar);//this should be XXX
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just to access things from child class your parent class' items should not be `private`, otherwise it will work:

```
class Controller
{
    //protected $myvar="defaultCaption";
    public $myvar="defaultCaption"; // to access this from outside the class 

    public function __construct() 
    {
        echo $this->myvar;
    }
}

class myController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->myvar = 'myCaption';

        parent::__construct();
    }
}

$mc = new myController; // outputs: myCaption
```

Comment: No, my problem is that I want to share some data between classes, but I do not like to use global variables.

Comment: it's just example how you can access parent class variables, it's not global variable, it's class' property

Comment: you can use `$this->myvar = 'myCaption';` anywhere in child class

Comment: @poostchi I've updated answer: it's easy just make `myvar` public will do the job